# How to select files that begin with a certain word in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, filesystems

I have a small php app that needs to read multiple xml data files. The files will be generated in the following fashion:

```
contractors1.xml
contractors2.xml
contractors3.xml
...
contractors100.xml
```

How do I select any file in the directory that begins with "contractors" followed by a number that ends with ".xml"?

Answer (score 7):

```
glob()
```

is the function you need to do that.

This should work

```
<?php
foreach (glob("contractors*.xml") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
?>
```